# Update a single item in a nested case class

Tags: monocle-scala

The university [example](https://julien-truffaut.github.io/Monocle/examples/university_example.html) explains how to update all items of a map:

```
(allLecturers composeLens salary).modify(_ + 2)(uni)
```

To **set** a single item, one can use this cumbersome code:

```
(departments composeLens at("History")).set(Some(Department(30, List(Lecturer("arnold", "stones", 30)))))(uni)
```

To **update** a single item, I wrote:

```
def updateBudget(department: Option[Department]): Option[Department] = {
    val budgetLens = GenLens[Department](_.budget)
    Some(budgetLens.set(40)(department.get))
}
(departments composeLens at("History")).modify(updateBudget)(uni)
```

Is there a more elegant syntax for this?

---

With Lists, the Optionals are not necessary:

```
val lecturers = GenLens[Department](_.lecturers)

def updateSalary(lecturer: Lecturer): Lecturer =
    GenLens[Lecturer](_.salary).set(40)(lecturer)

(lecturers composeOptional index(0)).modify(updateSalary)(dep)
```

Or, even more compact:

```
(lecturers composeOptional index(0)).modify((l: Lecturer) => l.lens(_.salary).set(40))(dep)
```